# Abnormal termination of GAMESS in frequencies calculation

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry

I want to optimize geometry and to analyse frequencies for transition metals ($\ce{Cu}$, $\ce{Mn}$, etc.) compounds using GAMESS. I use Avogadro for preparing input files and I have a problem: one of my calculations terminates abnormally with the following message in the output file.

> NO FORCE FIELD, SCF DOES NOT CONVERGE AT VIB0 POINT
>   EXECUTION OF GAMESS TERMINATED -ABNORMALLY- AT Thu Mar 26

What is the actual problem and how can I overcome it?

Comment: Consider adding at least the input file so we can see what can be changed.

Comment: Looks like there are some problems with the SCF convergence. First, try a bigger number of SCF iterations by setting MAXIT to, say, 100 in [$CONTRL group](http://myweb.liu.edu/~nmatsuna/gamess/input/CONTRL.html).

Comment: In Avogadro GAMESS Input Generator choose "Advanced Setup" tab and set "Max SCF Iterations" to 100.

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.SE! I want to second @Wildcat's request. Adding the input file could really help.